# Implementing a simple sign up/log in system in Rails using cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rest, architecture

I'm fairly new to Rails and I'm trying to implement a really basic user authentication system. My main problem right now is that I do not have a clue what's a good design for this.

**What I have now**

My Rails app is not a website; it's a webservice that communicates with an iPhone app. All communication is in JSON.

When a user *signs up*, the app sends a POST request to `/users.json` with `name` and `password` as JSON in the HTTP body. Rails then saves the user id in a cookie:

```
cookies.signed[:user_id] = @user.id
```

When a user *logs out*, the app sends a POST request to `/logout.json`. Rails gets the user id from the cookie, updates the database and deletes the cookie.

Later, when the user wants to *log in* again, the app sends a POST request to `/login.json` with `name` and `password` as JSON in the HTTP body. Rails sets the cookie again.

**My question(s)**

1. Is this design RESTful? Because login and logout aren't resources.
2. Is it secure to use cookies like this? I'm planning to use SSL.
3. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tt's a very basic approach

A more RESTful way:

Create a controller called sessions with a create and destroy action. Throw the login/logout out of your head and start thinking in sessions. A login is just a username/password combination. When you login you create/start a session, when you log out you destroy the session. The login is not affected.

Instead of using cookies.signed[:user_id] you should use session[:user_id]

SSL is a big plus, because the password can't be sniffed through the network.

And there are lots of out-of-the-box authentication systems.

My favourite is Devise:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

Comment: Should a session be saved in the database? If not, how can I delete a session if it doesn't have an id? And what is the benefit of session[] over cookies[]?

Comment: Hi, where you store the session is up to you - by default rails stores the session encrypted in a cookie. The cookie is the session id. You can change the session adapter to use a database. You can not delete a cookie session directly but you can set an expiry date or if you want to be able to force a log out you could work with timestamps/tokens which are checked on every hit on your page. If you decide to store the session in a database, you will have better control over who is logged in, and you can kick people out selectively. I'm using redis (key/value database) for sessions.

Answer (score 1):

there is a nice screencast ryan bates did on authentication from scratch

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Answer (score 0):

1. No, for the reason you stated.
2. No, you need to pass a second parameter to encrypt the user's id.
3. Well, you could [use a gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), there's a few about.

If you do want to code it yourself, then I'd recommend looking at a tutorial. The one at [railstutorial.org](http://railstutorial.org) is pretty good.

The basic idea is to create a user model with an encrypted password, which uses a salt formed from the current time and password. You then create a sessions controller and make it RESTful, but using cookies instead of another resource. Make sure to encrypt the cookie with the salt as well:

```
cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
```